# segregating php object variables

Tags: php, xml, variables, object

I have some XML that is being returned to be as an object, like this:

```
SwitchvoxResponse Object
(
[apiStatus:private] => success
[apiErrors:private] => Array
    (
    )

[apiResult:private] => Array
    (
        [calls] => Array
            (
                [page_number] => 1
                [total_pages] => 1
                [items_per_page] => 50
                [total_items] => 1
                [call] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 14301
                                [origination] => outgoing
                                [start_time] => 2011-06-17 13:40:58
                                [from] => CALLER_NAME <4485>
                                [from_account_id] => 1120
                                [from_name] => CALLER_NAME
                                [from_number] => 4485
                                [to] => CALLEE_NAME <6534>
                                [to_account_id] => 1101
                                [to_name] => CALLEE_NAME
                                [to_number] => 6534
                                [total_duration] => 47
                                [talk_duration] => 43
                                [events] => Array
                                    (
                                        [event] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [start_time] => 2011-06-17 13:40:58
                                                        [type] => OUTGOING
                                                        [display] => Dialed number (6534)
                                                    )

                                                [1] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [start_time] => 2011-06-17 13:40:58
                                                        [type] => INTERNAL
                                                        [display] => Rang CALLEE_NAME <6534>
                                                    )

                                                [2] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [start_time] => 2011-06-17 13:41:02
                                                        [type] => TALKING
                                                        [display] => Talked to CALLEE_NAME <6534> for 43 seconds
                                                    )

                                                [3] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [start_time] => 2011-06-17 13:41:45
                                                        [type] => HANGUP
                                                        [display] => Call was hung up by CALLER_NAME <4485>
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

How do I pull out the values of these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results can be accessed via the `SwitchvoxResponse::getResult()` method. Given `$object` is the `SwitchvoxResponse` object quoted in the question, the example below loops over each `call` and prints the `from` values.

```
$result = $object->getResult();
foreach ($result['calls']['call'] as $call) {
    echo $call['from'];
}
```

Similarly, the response status is fetched via `$object->getResponseStatus()` and any errors via `$object->getErrors()`.

The response statuses can be one of `SV_RESPONSE_SUCCESS`, `SV_RESPONSE_FAULT` or `SV_RESPONSE_FAILED`.

---

**Edit re. comments**

To get the items for the first call only, simply do:

```
$result = $object->getResult();
$call = $result['calls']['call'][0];
// And access the values like
echo $call['from_name'];
```

Comment: This returns every instance of the [to_number] field.  I need to pull just the value from call [0].  Adding ['0'] does not work, nor does ['1'] etc....

Comment: The `$result` is just the array at `[call]` in your `print_r()` output in the question. One would assume you know how to traverse arrays, do you?

Comment: Ahh okay, well I've added a quick example above. If you have general questions on working with arrays, perhaps best to ask a whole new question on that subject.

Comment: I've tried this, and get this result:
`1o2M1M41187`
`Notice: Undefined index: to_number in...`

Comment: It looks like not every call will contain all of the items that you might want.  You will have to check whether it exists before trying to use it (e.g. with [`if`](http://php.net/if) and [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists)).

Comment: Got it, thank you.  I knew the gist of this, but was unaware of the getResult() bit.  wouldve taken me loads more googling, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're very welcome. Good luck with the rest of your script. :)

Answer (score 0):

All three properties are marked `private`, so they would have to be obtained through accessor methods marked `public`